# How to use caffemodel with OpenCV on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, caffe

I am trying to use a `.caffemodel` alongside OpenCV on iOS devices. I found this [github repository](https://github.com/noradaiko/caffe-ios-sample), but it can only be built with Xcode 6. I am working with Xcode 7, but I also downloaded Xcode 6 and still have no success on building it.

*How can I use a caffemodel with OpenCV on iOS 9?*

PS: The alternative would be [this](http://deeplearningkit.org/) but it's written with swift & metal and I need to be able to use it with OpenCV.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do it ?
Is it possible to use DNN with ios, as I see a flag in cmakelists, that dnn module will be disabled for apple framework and winrt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV DNN contrib module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/dnn).

You need first to build OpenCV with contrib modules, you can find the steps [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d25/tutorial_dnn_build.html).

Then you can import and use the `.caffemodel` following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html).

Here is an updated version of the tutorial, since it's not working as is:

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
/* Find best class for the blob (i. e. class with maximal probability) */
void getMaxClass(dnn::Blob &probBlob, int *classId, double *classProb)
{
    Mat probMat = probBlob.matRefConst().reshape(1, 1); //reshape the blob to 1x1000 matrix
    Point classNumber;
    minMaxLoc(probMat, NULL, classProb, NULL, &classNumber);
    *classId = classNumber.x;
}
std::vector<String> readClassNames(const char *filename = "synset_words.txt")
{
    std::vector<String> classNames;
    std::ifstream fp(filename);
    if (!fp.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "File with classes labels not found: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    std::string name;
    while (!fp.eof())
    {
        std::getline(fp, name);
        if (name.length())
            classNames.push_back( name.substr(name.find(' ')+1) );
    }
    fp.close();
    return classNames;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::dnn::initModule();        

    String modelTxt = "bvlc_googlenet.prototxt";
    String modelBin = "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel";
    String imageFile = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "space_shuttle.jpg";
    Ptr<dnn::Importer> importer;
    try                                     //Try to import Caffe GoogleNet model
    {
        importer = dnn::createCaffeImporter(modelTxt, modelBin);
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception &err)        //Importer can throw errors, we will catch them
    {
        std::cerr << err.msg << std::endl;
    }
    if (!importer)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't load network by using the following files: " << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "prototxt:   " << modelTxt << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "caffemodel: " << modelBin << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel can be downloaded here:" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    dnn::Net net;
    importer->populateNet(net);
    importer.release();                     //We don't need importer anymore
    Mat img = imread(imageFile);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't read image from the file: " << imageFile << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    resize(img, img, Size(224, 224));                   //GoogLeNet accepts only 224x224 RGB-images
    dnn::Blob inputBlob = dnn::Blob(img);   //Convert Mat to dnn::Blob batch of images
    net.setBlob(".data", inputBlob);        //set the network input
    net.forward();                          //compute output
    dnn::Blob prob = net.getBlob("prob");   //gather output of "prob" layer
    int classId;
    double classProb;
    getMaxClass(prob, &classId, &classProb);//find the best class
    std::vector<String> classNames = readClassNames();
    std::cout << "Best class: #" << classId << " '" << classNames.at(classId) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Probability: " << classProb * 100 << "%" << std::endl;
    return 0;
} //main
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found this tutorial and tried to run it on my machine (not for iOS). However, I had a problem with this function `dnn::Blob::fromImages(img);` it couldn't be found. But let me try this with `cv::dnn::initModule();` and I'll come back. Also the `contrib_modules` are not in the iOS opencv version right?

Comment: No, contrib modules are not in the prebuild binaries. I had some difficulties running this tutorial first time, too. So, let me know ;D

Comment: Ok, so I've tried to use the `cv::dnn::initModule()` but still get this error `No member named 'fromImages' in cv::dnn::Blob`

Comment: I am sure I have OpenCV with the contrib modules

Comment: Which OpenCV version do you have?

Comment: Have you linked to opencv_dnnXXX.lib?

Comment: Oh... try `cv::dnn::Blob inputBlob = cv::dnn::Blob(img); `, I don't have the `fromImages`

Comment: OpenCV version : 3.1.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121553/discussion-between-cchacholiades-and-miki).

Comment: The links of this answer are not available anymore: can please correct that? Plus from the link https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules I can only see `dnn_objdetect`: is this the DNN module I should use?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi dnn module changed a lot from version 3.2, and this answer is now (after more than 2 years) obsolete. Yes, it should be "dnn_objdetect"

Comment: `dnn` exists already inside the standard opencv (not the contrib_modules) but the module does not contain `initModule`. I will investigate further.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi ah right, the dnn module is now moved into standard opencv. It's been a while since I used it, so I cannot tell about recent developments. Good luck

Comment: Sorry another question: when loading the model trained in Caffe did it happen to u also to have to load the means to be subtracted before inputting? I have such means contained in a file named `mean.binaryproto` but it is not clear how to load them in OpenCV.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi have a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/178680/how-to-use-meanbinaryproto-with-blobfromimages/). When I worked on it I generated my model an I saved the mean in a different file format, so I can't tell. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I will post another answer because with recent versions there are some differences.

First of all now `dnn` is already inside the standard OpenCV library so you do not have to build it from `contrib_modules`.

The function to load the network is `readNetFromCaffe`.

For example the following code load the NN:

```
  std::string modelName = "path/to/mymodel.caffemodel";

  std::string protoName = "path/to/deploy.prototxt";
  cv::dnn::Net net;
  try
  {
    net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(protoName, modelName);
  }
  catch (cv::Exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    if (net.empty())
    {
      std::cerr << "Can't load network by using the following files: " << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "prototxt:   " << protoName << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "caffemodel: " << modelName << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel can be downloaded here:" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel" << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
```

Then you can run the NN:

```
  cv::Mat res_mat;
  float res;
  cv::Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(roi, 1.0f, cv::Size(227, 227),
                                  cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), false);
  net.setInput(inputBlob);
  //During the forward pass output of each network layer is computed,
  //but in this example we need output from "prob" layer only.
  res_mat = net.forward("score");
  std::cout<<res_mat<<std::endl;
  res_mat = res_mat.reshape(1, 1); //reshape the blob to 1x2 matrix
  return res_mat.at<float>(0);
```

The function `cv::dnn::blobFromImage` resize the image to the input network size specified by the third argument (in my case `cv::Size(227, 227)`). The argument  `cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0)` is to subtract the means from the three `BGR` channels.

`score` is the name of the output layer in the NN I used. You can see this information in the `prototxt` file.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do the same and found myself in the same situation. But with a newer version of OpenCV